# Unable to pass variable value in XSLT within a template

Tags: xslt, comparison, sgml

The below is my sgml file structure:

```
<em>
<pgblk revdate="20130901">

    <task revdate='20140901'>
        <p>random texts and few more inner tags</p>
    </task>
    <task revdate='20150901'>
        <p>random texts and few more inner tags</p>
    </task>
    <task revdate='20160901'>
        <p>random texts and few more inner tags</p>
    </task>
</pgblk>
```

I have many tags with same name (task tag) and am trying to get the greatest revdate here. My XSLT is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/pgblk">
        <xsl:variable name="updatedrevdate">
            <xsl:for-each select="task">
                <xsl:sort select="@revdate" data-type="number" order="descending" />
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@revdate" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now i am getting the greatest task tag value..but when i use the condition inside the same template to compare the greatest tag and the pageblock value

"Operations to PRINT THE GREATEST REVDATE"

The comparison is always getting the first revdate from task and comparing with pageblock revdate. It is not getting the greatest from the task.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share the code that is performing the comparison between the `@revdate` of `<pgblk>` and variable `$updatedrevdate`?

Comment: <xsl:when test="pgblk/@revdate &gt; $updatedrevdate ">

 <xsl:call-template name="set.printheader">
           <xsl:with-param name="revdate" select="@revdate"/>
</xsl:call-template>

Comment: My bad. Should have put my comment in a better way. Please help understand the following _The comparison is always getting the first revdate from task_ with your code. If it is possible, please edit the question and add more XSLT code since the current code only performs sorting and is correctly giving back the max date from task.

Comment: I'm having to guess exactly what your code does, but if the path expression `pgblk/@revdate` is used in a template with `match="pgblk"`, then the chances are it selects an empty node-set, and a comparison in which one operand is an empty node-set is always false.

Comment: Also, the template matches `/pgblk` which would mean `pgblk` would have to be the root element, but in the XML sample, `em` is the root.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the following XSLT code helps you make changes to your code. Need to change the template matching to

```
<xsl:template match="pgblk">
```

The solution does the comparison and outputs the dates.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="pgblk">
        <xsl:variable name="updatedrevdate">
            <xsl:for-each select="task">
                <xsl:sort select="@revdate" data-type="number" order="descending" />
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@revdate" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- output the dates -->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Page Block Date: ', @revdate)" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Max Task Date: ', $updatedrevdate)" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@revdate &gt; $updatedrevdate">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('Max date after comparison: ', @revdate)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('Max date after comparison: ', $updatedrevdate)" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
Page Block Date: 20130901
Max Task Date: 20160901
Max date after comparison: 20160901
```

Comment: yes, im doing an operation similar to the one above. IT should work fine but for some reasons the comparison is still taking only the first revdate into consideration. The match is now match=pgblk level as per the above comment.